# OData Queries on Entities with Dynamic Fields

Tags: c#, .net-core, odata, dynamic-class-creation, dynamic-class

I am using **OData** on a dynamic model. The `MyObject` data is stored in two different ways on the database - in a main `MyObject` table and in a secondary table of key/value pairs. The allowed field names for the secondary table are stored in a third table. Using a **PIVOT**, I can retrieve a list of `MyObject` items with both static and dynamic fields included. I am also able to use `$top`, `$filter`, and `$orderby` on any static fields if I assign the builder's `EntitySet` to the `MyObject` model. However, I am unable to use `$filter` or `$orderby` with any of the dynamic fields because they do not exist on the `MyObject` model.

I have tried creating a dynamic model using `DynamicObject` or `ExpandoObject` and using in place of `MyObject`, but am still unable to run `$filter` or `$orderby` on any fields that are not previously defined. In every case, the code fails before it hits the controller with a message that the field does not exist on whatever model is being assigned to the builder. Since I need to account for different users have different fields, as well as allowing new fields to be included automatically, I do not know how to set this up.

In the `Startup.cs` `ConfigureServices`, I have the following:

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.ModelBinderProviders.RemoveType<DateTimeModelBinderProvider>();
})
    .AddOData(opt => 
       opt.AddRouteComponents("odata", GetEdmModel())
           .Expand()
           .Select()
           .OrderBy()
           .Filter()
           .Count()
           .SkipToken()
     )
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

The `GetEdmModel` method is as follows:

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<MyObject>("MyObjectController");
builder.EntityType<MyObject>().HasKey(k => k.Id);
return builder.GetEdmModel();
```

I am not very familiar with setting up **OData**. Is there a way to use an `EntitySet` with a class that can be altered dynamically? Or is there a way to define something in the `EntityType` that can account for dynamic fields? I can get a list of these fields when the user calls the controller - before any queries need to be made on the `MyObject` entity.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work by removing the `EnableQuery` attribute on the `Get` method of `MyObjectController`. Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnet.odata.enablequeryattribute?view=odata-aspnetcore-7.0), this attribute prevents malicious queries. It seems that it is also preventing using any additional dynamic fields in `$filter` and `$orderby`.

I don't know if it is a great idea to remove this attribute, so I am still open to any other suggestions on how to handle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at OData's [Open Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/use-open-types-in-odata-v4). If your entity is defined like that you can query your dynamic properties with the normal `[EnableQuery]` attribute.